# What would a heterozygote advantage against rabies look like?

Tags: genetics, diseases, medicine, viruses

Some heterozygote advantages in humans are:

1. People with sickle-cell trait are resistant to malaria, but people with sickle-cell disease tend to die young.
2. Depending of the source we believe, people with one copy of a cystic fibrosis allele are immune to tuberculosis, or cholera, or typhoid fever (or two of them or all the three!) (it has been debunked).
3. People with one copy the CCR5-delta 32 allele are resistant to AIDS, when they have two copies, they are immune to AIDS, but they are at higher risk for West Nile virus disease complications.
4. People with Niemann-Pick disease type C are completely immune to ebolavirus-related hemorrhagic fever, and their heterozygous parents seem to be resistant against this disease caused by a filovirus.

So, I wonder what would a heterozygote advantage against rabies in humans look like. I ask because I am writing a story with a rabies pandemic that devastated most mammalian species including humans.

The molecular mechanism behind this is the DYNLL1 gene on chromosome 12 (the same chromosome as Von Willebrand factor).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Von Willebrand's disease:

[**Von Willebrand's disease**](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/von-willebrand-disease/symptoms-causes/syc-20354978) is an actual genetically inherited disease that causes abnormal clotting of the blood. People with the condition bleed more easily and for longer periods. Different variations of the disease can be more or less severe, and it's entirely plausible that a heterozygous mildly symptomatic version would confer some advantage (resistance), while a homozygous version would cause severe bleeding (but possibly confer virtual immunity).

The most likely scenario that would give you what I think you want is to have a gene very closely linked to the abnormal Von Willebrand's gene and in inherited along with the disease, to the point the disease is a marker for resistance. Otherwise, the two genes could share a promoter, so if a variant in the promoter gene increased or decreased expression of one, the other would, too.

Otherwise, the disease itself could confer resistance. I can't say exactly how the gene for Von Willebrand factor would cause a person to be resistant to rabies, since rabies is transmitted through the body along nerves, but your pandemic version is going to be a variant, so here's my best guess:

- The disease is transmitted differently, and exposure to the virus on the skin or in the nose somehow is able to trigger a lesion or stick to any damaged sight in the skin or mucus membranes. These lesions usually seal the virus into a clot, which can then invade the phagocytes that clean up the clot. Your people with Von Willebrand's disease are not making clots, and instead the virus tends to get flushed away with free-flowing blood before it has a chance to settle in.
- Heterozygous mildly symptomatic people are resistant to infection but will be slightly more vulnerable to bleeding problems. Homozygous individuals would suffer serious bleeding issues without medication, but would likely be more resistant to infection.
- If you used this mechanism, other people with bleeding disorders would likely also enjoy at least partial resistance to infection. I could see coumadin and aspirin being prescribed as a prophylactic against infection. In this scenario, various anticoagulants would likely confer similar resistance to infection. But if no one realized amidst a fast-spreading disease that people on anticoagulants were protected, then who in their right mind would start taking anticoagulants when there was a pandemic of insanity and mass-violence?

[**DYNLL1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DYNLL1) : Otherwise, the DYNLL1 gene itself can regulate [nitric oxide synthetase](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1089860309000366), which can affect a variety of neurological conditions. Nitric oxide regulation can affect memory and learning, so I could easily imagine a disease where heterozygous people are either resistant to or affected extremely slowly by infection with your para-rabies virus, but perhaps have some mild cognitive issues like being forgetful or having a tendency to struggle in school. Homozygous individuals might suffer serious cognitive deficits like [anterograde amnesia](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/21455-amnesia) or a strong predilection for [retrograde amnesia](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/21455-amnesia). These illnesses are so overdone in literature as to be a little stereotypical, but they're also super-fun.

- Imagine a person who suffered a bout of partial amnesia every time they became infected, and once their body beat off the infection, their memories gradually came back. Amidst a rabies pandemic, it would be great literature (and the stuff of horror movies to live through).

Answer (score 2):

**Asphyxiating thoracic dystrophy.**

https://rarediseases.org/rare-diseases/dystrophy-asphyxiating-thoracic/

> Synonyms of Asphyxiating Thoracic Dystrophy asphyxiating thoracic
> dysplasia ATD Jeune syndrome thoracic-pelvic-phalangeal dystrophy
> asphyxiating thoracic chondrodystrophy chondroectodermal
> dysplasia-like syndrome infantile thoracic dystrophy Jeune thoracic
> dystrophy General Discussion Summary
>
> Asphyxiating thoracic dystrophy (ATD) is a very rare form of skeletal
> dysplasia that primarily affects development of the bone structure of
> the chest (thorax) resulting in a very narrow and bell-shaped chest.
> Other major characteristics include kidney problems (due to renal cyst
> development), shortened bones of the arms and legs, extra fingers and
> toes, and a shortened stature.
>
> ATD is inherited as an autosomal recessive genetic disorder. It is
> caused by changes (mutations) in at least 24 different genes that
> encode for ciliary transport protein: IFT43/52/80/81/122/140/172,
> WDR19/34/35/60, DYNC2H1, DYNC2LI1, CEP120, NEK1, TTC21B, TCTEX1D2,
> INTU, TCTN3, EVC 1/2 and KIAA0586/0753.

These researchers knocked out (inactivated) DYNLL1 to see what it did.  The mutant mice had asphyxiating "short-rib" thoracic dystrophy.  The people at rare diseases should add that to the list, although I do not think there have been described any humans with thoracic dystrophy from a DYNLL1 mutation.

[Dynll1 is essential for development and promotes endochondral bone formation by regulating intraflagellar dynein function in primary cilia](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31009951/)

> ...we have generated Dynll1-deficient mouse strains.... Germline
> Dynll1 KO mice exhibit a severe ciliopathy-like phenotype similar to
> mice lacking another CD2 subunit, Dync2li1. Limb mesoderm-specific
> loss of Dynll1 results in severe bone shortening similar to human SRTD
> patients. Mechanistically, loss of Dynll1 leads to a partial depletion
> of other SRTD-related CD2 subunits, severely impaired retrograde
> intra-flagellar transport, significant thickening of primary cilia and
> cilia signaling defects. Interestingly, phenotypes of Dynll1-deficient
> mice are very similar to entirely cilia-deficient Kif3a/Ift88-null
> mice, except that they never present with polydactyly and retain
> relatively higher signaling outputs in parts of the hedgehog pathway.
> Compared to complete loss of Dynll1, maintaining very low DYNLL1
> levels in mice lacking the Dynll1-transcription factor ASCIZ (ATMIN)
> results in significantly attenuated phenotypes and improved CD2
> protein levels.

I propose that the DYNLL1 mutation that your people have is [dominant negative](https://www.genscript.com/biology-glossary/9431/dominant-negative) - its protein product is messed up and it messes up the protein product from the normal gene in the heterozygotes.  The result is the "significantly attenuated phenotype" described in the above abstract excerpt - very low activity of DNYLL1 which is enough to guide development but makes it hard for the pathogens that want to use it to move around.    These people are still short with narrow chests and short arms.  I think you should have the heterozygote rabies-proof humans still be polydactyl even though the mice were not, because that is good for a story.

Rabies is unusual in that it moves along inside nerves and apparently uses DNYLL1 to do it.
 [A Dynein Light Chain 1 Binding Motif in Rabies Virus Polymerase L Protein Plays a Role in Microtubule Reorganization and Viral Primary Transcription](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26157129/)

In an organism where DNYLL1 was much less available, the rabies would get lost, go the wrong way, and otherwise struggle to make it from the bite site to the brain.  I have this suspicion that the rabies virus would keep trying, though.  I propose here that it would take longer.  Maybe it would take long enough that the immune system could figure out about the rabies.
Or maybe these short, multifingered people would still die of rabies but it would take twenty years.